# How can I view the total run time of all the jobs for a given job name on Run:AI?

Tags: statistics, runai

I use [Run:AI](https://www.run.ai/) to launch AI experiments using GPU:

[image]

How can I view the total run time of all the jobs for a given job name on Run:AI?